# How to set a font for pdf output using Docx4J

Tags: java, docx4j

I am using `Docx4J.toPDF(wordMLPackage, new FOS("path/to/file.pdf"))` in order to convert a `".docx"` file to `".pdf"`. Although the conversion is happening fine but the original document had *Calibri* font and the resultant pdf has *Arial*. Is there a way to set the font while doing this conversion.

It would be better if you could give some link to how font properties can be set in general like **font size, font family** etc, if there is facility for that.

I searched online but could not find any help on this. Waiting for your responses. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you will have to embend the Calibiri font (file) into the PDF. I am using Calibri in generated PDFs as well and this is what i had to do. I was using PDFe

I dont know how how to do this in `docx4j`, but in case of iText(that I am using) I had to register the font like this

```
    FontFactory.registerDirectory("./resources/fonts/", true);
    com.itextpdf.text.Font iFont = FontFactory.getFont(font, getEncodingForFont(font), true);
```

and after this, iFont was automaticly embended into PDF so it can be displayed correctly on systems that does not have `Calibri` installed.

This may be related to your issue 
http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/embedded-fonts-not-used-in-pdf-conversion-t1137.html

And also there seems to be something into the canse on SO already: [How to change font encoding when converting docx -> pdf with docx4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327977/how-to-change-font-encoding-when-converting-docx-pdf-with-docx4j)

Comment: +1 Thanks for quick response. I am not sure if it happens similary in docx4j as in iText but the link u provided seem to have some information. On it!.

Comment: @AdityaBahuguna also check the second link to SO that i have added. There is a straightforward way how to apply propert font into PDF during conversion.

Comment: I will mark your answer accepted as the info u gave is correct. Quoting from the Docx4J documentation "When docx4j is used to create a PDF, it can only use fonts which are available to it.These fonts come from 2 sources: 1) those installed on the computer 2)those embedded in the document" - So i think I will embed it, for portability. Rest should work automatically because the method I am using is a Facade to pdf conversion and the fallback options must be there.

Comment: @AdityaBahuguna yes, embending is the way to go, because if you would try to open your document on system that does not have `Calibri` installed, text in PDF will fallback to the default font. Due to that fact the same PDF can look different on 2 different machines - thus the embending makes it realy "Portable Document Format" :) I am glad I could help.